# retrieve in android application user's friends

Tags: android, facebook

I have android application in which for a logged facebook user to retrieve in your android application all his friends in a similiar way with this picture:
http://i55.tinypic.com/wv9vzb.png (this is taken from iphone but I want something similar to this).

I've integrated facebook into my application using facebook-sdk.

If someone could point me into the right direction I would be gratefull.Thanks!

UPDATE:

I tried loading the URL with your code :

```
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    Log.d("We are:","Loading Picture");
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";

    try{
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.d("And:","Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the logcat looks like this:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed out
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStreamImpl(Native Method)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStream(OSNetworkSystem.java:478)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:61)
   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.readln(HttpURLConnection.java:1178)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.readServerResponse(HttpURLConnection.java:1250)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.sendRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1238)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnection.java:1558)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1551)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1052)
     at java.net.URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler.getContent(URLConnection.java:1053)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:166)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.getContent(HttpsURLConnection.java:156)
   at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:621)
    at com.facebook.android.Example.getUserPic(Example.java:192)
    at com.facebook.android.Example$2.onClick(Example.java:174)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
```

I must say that when I type the URL in the browser it shows me the correct profile picture.

I tried also to load the URL by doing a `http post`:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(imageURL);

        try{

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if(response!=null)
        {
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

            }
       }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the logcat looks like this:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
   at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  at com.facebook.android.Example.getUserPic(Example.java:203)
   at com.facebook.android.Example$2.onClick(Example.java:174)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
```

What's wrong?:-S

Comment: I'm not quite sure from looking at the log what is causing the error, i've never had a "Authority expected at index 7" exception before! If you want you can zip up the project, post a link, and i'll download it and see if i can work out what the issue is?

Comment: The example I'm trying on is one from facebook-sdk.....should I zip it all...or only the class in which I tried these things?Do u wanna run the project????

Comment: http://dl.transfer.ro/simple-transfer_RO-16jul-7b53ea.zip  If u gonna run it:first press the request button and after that Request profile picture! button.Thank u!

Comment: The class in which u should look is Example.java at the first 3-4 methods:)Thank u!

Comment: Just tested it, it worked with no errors on my handset and also on the emulator so there are no issues with your code! Very Strange!!!

Comment: yes....that's true...but if u look in logcat there says that Bitmap returned null.The Bitmap returned I've putted in a ImageView...and there  is nothing displayed.Cause the bitmap returned nulll....I mean profile picture==null;)

Comment: It worked for me, returned a bitmap - so i dont know what the issue is!

Comment: @Kenny let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1541/discussion-between-george-and-kenny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to get the users friends by making a request to the graph api (`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?`) this will return all the data in a JSON-encoded array.

You can then create a list of all the friends and download the pictures using the ids and the url `"http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small"`

For an example project whichs shows you how to create a list with images downloaded from a url take a look at my answer to this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638701/setting-up-dynamic-listactivity/6666943#6666943)

Hope this helps to get you started!

---

Here is the code i use to download the users photo, it will return a bitmap that you can then set in an image view by calling `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

```
/**
 * Function loads the users facebook profile pic
 * 
 * @param userID
 */
public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {
    String imageURL;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading Picture");
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've succeded to return the names and the id's of the friends, but could u please guide a little bit at the part with the picture.If I'll make that request ".../picture.." what it will be returned?Thank u!

Comment: I've added the code i use to download the users pics, hope this helps.

Comment: I'm facing a problem with the URL a think....when I type it in a browser it works...but in code I don't know what goes wrong cause I get an ugly error.Could I post the logcat here and take a look at it?Thanks

Comment: Yeah post it in the question and i'll have a look.